# How to make global context variable in django

Tags: django

here i have some dynamic logo and image.I want to apply them in all the view but for that i have to pass site_data context to each view and it isp very time consuming.So isn't there any solutions so that i can pass site_data context to all the view at one time

> models.py

```
class SiteSetting(models.Model):
    background_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Background Image',default='NoImageFound.jpg')
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='logo',default='NoImageFound.jpg')
```

> views.py

```
def view_student(request):
    students = Student.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    site_data = SiteSetting.objects.all().order_by('-date').first()
    return render(request, 'admin/view_students.html', {'students': students, 'site_data':site_data,'title': 'All Students'})
```

> template

```
    <link rel="icon" href="{{site_data.logo.url}}">
```

Comment: Use [context_processors](https://www.webforefront.com/django/setupdjangocontextprocessors.html) or [middleware](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/18/how-to-create-a-custom-django-middleware.html). If you use middleware, you must be sure the middleware works only for the paths you want to (not static, media, admin, etc...) The best option would be context_processors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [context_processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext)

> context_processors.py

```
from .models import SiteSetting

def get_site_data(request):
    site_data = SiteSetting.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    return {"site_data": site_data}
```

Add this context processor in your `settings.py`.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ....
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'path.to.context_processors.get_site_data',

            ],
        },
    },
]
```